# Touchscreen gestures are not working in Firefox on Windows 10/11 despite being enabled in the settings

Tags: firefox

I am running Firefox on a 2-1 Lenovo windows laptop and none of the touchscreen or touchpad gestures works. It is like they are not enabled but they are.

Swipe left or right on the screen should trigger navigation back / forward but nothing happens. Similar with the touchpad. The only gesture that works is pinch zoom on the touchpad.

Touch appears to be configured in the settings (default values)

[image: browser.gesture settings]

Update: There is a new experimental trackpad swipe gesture. Go to about:config and set widget.disable-swipe-tracker to false.
This made swipe navigation start working on my touchpad.

Any idea about how to get touch enabled on the touch screen as well?

This issue persists reinstall of windows / Firefox and I have never seen touchscreen gestures work in Firefox on this device.

Comment: It seems to be on by default since Firefox 99, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1348786 , but I can't seem to figure out how to turn it off (on linux). Setting widget.disable-swipe-tracker to false seems to do nothing. I keep "going back" when trying to scroll...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. After a bit of investigation I have found that there is no support for touch screen gestures in Firefox. I have found a 5 year old bug report about this. The positive news is that there is a recent case updates, where it says that they will start to look at implementing touchscreen support

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1443710

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who is still looking for a fix, **change this to** `false` in `about:config`

```
widget.disable-swipe-tracker
```

found in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1539730#c26

Comment: This doesn't work for me (flag is already set to false). I'm running Windows (like the OP) whereas that thread seems to be referring to installs on Linux.